# Python: If filename in specified path contains string, then move to folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil, python-os, fnmatch

New to python here.
I would like to create a script that will scan my directory and if the filename contains a certain string in it, then it will automatically move to a folder of my choice.
Have tried this, but to no luck:

```
import os
import shutil
import fnmatch
import glob

ffe_path = 'E:/FFE'
new_path = 'E:/FFE/Membership/letters'
keyword = 'membership'


os.chdir('E:/FFE/Membership')
os.mkdir('letters')



source_dir = 'E:/FFE'
dest_dir = 'E:/FFE/Membership/letters'

os.chdir(source_dir)

for top, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
    for filename in files:
        if not filename.endswith('.docx'):
            continue
        file_path = os.path.join(top, filename)
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            if '*membership' in f.read():
                shutil.move(file_path, os.path.join(dest_dir, filename))
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `f.read()` reads the file. You don't want that right?

Comment: Haha that was likely pulled from my research online and got mixed up with looking in the file and reading merely just the filename. No, I just mean to scan the filenames in the directory.

Comment: In that case, look at my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple function will do the trick:

```
def copyCertainFiles(source_folder, dest_folder, string_to_match, file_type=None):
    # Check all files in source_folder
    for filename in os.listdir(source_folder):
        # Move the file if the filename contains the string to match
        if file_type == None:
            if string_to_match in filename:
                shutil.move(os.path.join(source_folder, filename), dest_folder)

        # Check if the keyword and the file type both match
        elif isinstance(file_type, str):
            if string_to_match in filename and file_type in filename:
                shutil.move(os.path.join(source_folder, filename), dest_folder)
```

source_folder = full/relative path of source folder

dest_folder = full/relative path of destination folder (will need to be created beforehand)

string_to_match = a string basis which the files will be copied

file_type (optional) = if only a particular file type should be moved.

You can, of course make this function even better, by having arguments for ignoring case, automatically creating a destination folder if it does not exist, copying all files of a particular filetype if no keyword is specified and so on. Furthermore, you can also use regexes to match filetypes, which will be far more flexible.

Comment: Thanks. The script moves files with exact match to the string, but does not work on filenames that are a partial match (containing the string among other words). I am getting this error.   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8VgV.png

Comment: Are your folder paths correct? I use linux, but I'm quite sure that Windows file paths do not have both forward and back slashes (see E:/FFE\Membership)

Comment: It is now only backslashes (/)

Answer (score 1):

`f.read` reads the file. You most likely don't want to see if the string is in a file's contents. I fixed your code to look in the file's name:

```
import os
import shutil
import fnmatch
import glob

ffe_path = 'E:/FFE'
new_path = 'E:/FFE/Membership/letters'
keyword = 'membership'


os.chdir('E:/FFE/Membership')
os.mkdir('letters')



source_dir = 'E:/FFE'
dest_dir = 'E:/FFE/Membership/letters'

os.chdir(source_dir)

for top, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
    for filename in files:
        if not filename.endswith('.docx'):
            continue
        file_path = os.path.join(top, filename)
        if '*membership' in filename:
            shutil.move(file_path, os.path.join(dest_dir, filename))
```

Comment: Is it a different function/method if the keyword is bunched in the filename? Ie. 2019_0120_Memberslist

Comment: @patriciajlim -- I'm not sure I understood your question.

Comment: I suspect that he just wants to scan for `'membership'` in the `filename`, not the `filepath`, which also means that you can move the line that creates the `filepath` inside the last `if`.

Comment: @GlennMackintosh -- Yes, I fixed that.

Comment: Edit: The code works. Not moving my files containing 'membership'... I feel that I am missing something in my script.